# Why use a JWT Refresh Token

Tags: jwt

Why use a JWT Refresh Token.
At https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/refreshing-access-tokens/
to use refresh token i need to send

```
POST / oauth / HTTP / 1.1 token
Host: authorization-server.com
 
grant_type = refresh_token
& refresh_token = xxxxxxxxxxx
& client_id = xxxxxxxxxx
& client_secret = xxxxxxxxxx
```

What is the point of using refresh_token since I can request an access token directly

```
POST / HTTP token / 1.1
Host: authorization-server.com
 
grant_type = client_credentials
& client_id = xxxxxxxxxx
& client_secret = xxxxxxxxxx
```

The service I am connecting to requires client_id and client_secret to refresh token. Without these parameters, it returns

```
{
     "error": "invalid_request",
     "error_description": "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed."
}
```

when appending client_id and client_secret, it returns a valid JWT

Comment: For security purposes, access tokens are only valid for a short amount of time. Refresh tokens are used to refresh the access tokens without the need to log in again. There is plenty more information on this topic: https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/ https://auth0.com/docs/security/tokens/refresh-tokens

Comment: I understand the difference between access tokens and refresh tokens. I don't understand why client_id & client_secret is required in the refresh tokens request. This means that I have to save or download client_secret somewhere from the user.

Answer (score 0):

First I quote the [official documentation](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/refreshing-access-tokens/):

> Client Authentication (required if the client was issued a secret):
> Typically, refresh tokens are only used with confidential clients. However, since it is possible to use the authorization code flow without a client secret, the refresh grant may also be used by clients that don’t have a secret. If the client was issued a secret, then the client must authenticate this request. Typically the service will allow either additional request parameters client_id and client_secret, or accept the client ID and secret in the HTTP Basic auth header. If the client does not have a secret, then no client authentication will be present in this request.

Some applications (e.g. web apps) can store client's secret safely and therefore it is better to provide client's secret in refresh token's flow but for some applications (e.g mobile apps) which cannot store client's secret safely, it is recommended to issue a refresh token that does not require client's secret.

Moreover, some authorization processes can be done without the client's secret and hence it must be possible to issue a refresh token without the requirement of the client's secret.

If the client was issued a secret, then it must provide the secret for refresh token flow.

Different services typically have the option to issue both a refresh token that requires authentication and one that does not.

For the service you are using, check whether it has the option to issue you a refresh token that does not require the client's secret for its flow.

Comment: There is not. REST API requires client_id and client_secret to refresh the token.

Comment: In that case, you have to contact the service's support.